# What is the behavior of initializing a struct with `StructType structInstance = {};`?

Tags: c++, struct

What is the behavior of initializing a struct with `StructType structInstance = {};`? Does it simply use default constructors and/or initialize all member data as null? See the following for an example from a tutorial on Vulkan:

```
VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello Triangle";
appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
appInfo.pEngineName = "No Engine";
appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;
```

Comment: It depends on the details of the "struct".

Comment: @Justin no, it does not do that at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkApplicationInfo.html),  `VkApplicationInfo` is an *aggregate*. Furthermore, it only contains members of scalar (primitive) type.

Initializing an aggregate with `{ }` means that each member is initialized as if by `{ }`. The constructor is not called.

Initializing a scalar type with `{ }` is equivalent to initializing with `= 0`.  So the enum and members of integer type are initialized to zero, and the pointers are initialized to null pointers.

Note: For non-aggregate structs, the object would be [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).